# How to evaluate Latex and a variable in a ggplot title?

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex

I often want to display both Latex and the underlying value of a variable in a ggplot title, but my existing methods seem to only work for one or the other.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(latex2exp)
```

```
MY_VARIABLE <- 1000
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
    geom_point() + 
    labs(title = TeX(r'(Can I use $\LaTeX$ with MY_VARIABLE)')))
```

[image]

```
MY_VARIABLE <- 1000
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
    geom_point() + 
    labs(title = glue('Can I use \\LaTeX with {MY_VARIABLE}'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option using `paste0` with `TeX`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(latex2exp)
MY_VARIABLE <- 1000
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = TeX(paste0('Can I use \\LaTeX with', MY_VARIABLE)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the output of `glue` to `TeX`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(latex2exp)

MY_VARIABLE <- 1000
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
    geom_point() + 
    labs(title = TeX(glue('Can I use \\LaTeX with {MY_VARIABLE}')))
```

[image]